# SnapLineSnapResult for objects in JavaFx

Tags: javafx

Currently I have a project that is being used to draw rooms with lines and images that can be selected by the user by hitting a button representing what they want to add. I.E. if they want a shower a button for shower is pressed and an image appears in a pane. The shower can be resized and moved in the pane. The user also has the ability to use lines to draw objects or walls. The lines can be resized, rotated, or moved. I am now trying to get these objects to interact with each other. Say a user is using lines to make an object, and when the line comes near another object the line being moved snaps to the other object. I have found a 3rd party library that has SnapLineSnapResult but I don't see anything where someone has used it. Is this something that is desktop JavaFX usable, or is it a touch operation and does anyone have code to model or another solution?

[SnapLineSnapResult](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesjavafx/doc/api/com/yworks/yfiles/input/SnapLineSnapResult.html)

My code for line that would be useful if I can use this class is as follows:

```
    line.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event1) -> {
                    // in resize region
                    if (isInResizeZoneLine(line, event1)) {
                        // adjust line
                        line.setEndX(event1.getX());
                    }
                    // in movable region
                    else {
                        Point2D currentPointer = new Point2D(event1.getX(), event1.getY());
                        if (bound.getBoundsInLocal().contains(currentPointer)) {
   /*--------*/             // potential place for if (near other object to be snapped)
                            double lineWidth = line.getEndX() - line.getStartX();
                            line.setStartY(currentPointer.getY());
                            line.setEndY(currentPointer.getY());
                            line.setStartX(currentPointer.getX() - lineWidth/2);
                            line.setEndX(currentPointer.getX() + lineWidth/2);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That's not part of JavaFX; it's part of a third party library. As far as I can tell from a very quick review, that library is not integrated with JavaFX (looks like it integrates to some degree with AWT and Swing) - it also looks like it is all pre-Java 5.

Comment: James_D is looks like javafx 1.0 but it was the closest to what I wanted that I could find. I probably will end up having to do my own, but I was hoping for better GUI interaction than my "hacking."